# Mysqli : Does mysqli_close($conn) reduce stress?

Tags: php, mysqli

My question is very simple, Does using

```
 mysqli_close($conn);
```

Reduce the number of connections connected at the same time. I tested it though. What is I did was I wrote a PHP script in which I left the mysql connection open and ran a website stresser and saw that within few seconds the Sql hit the max connections limit i.e 151. Then I added `mysqli_close($conn)` to the script and ran the stresser and was surprised to see that the peak connections was only 18. So was this due to `mysqli_close` or just luck?

Comment: Test it again (and again) to confirm your original results and you'll soon find out if luck is on your side.

Comment: I am testing , but what do you think is it luck or it really works?

Comment: I bet on luck, connection is closed automatically.

Comment: How many result sets do you show producing the same results?

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard , can you elaborate you'r question.

Comment: Elaborate? How many tests have you run? What are the results? Do the aggregate results confirm that closing the connection frees up stress?

Comment: I did 5 tests for each script till now with 67 r/s and it seems that closing does reduce the stress.